# componentDidMount did not fire the render()

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am calling an async function in `componentDidMount()`, I expect after the state got updated with fetched data, the component should re-render, but no.

component code:

```
function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
        posts: state.posts
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch)
}

export default class Main extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.fetchData()
    }

    fetchData(){
        this.props.getAllPosts().then(() => {
            console.log('props: ' + JSON.stringify(this.props))
            this.props.posts.data.map( post => {
                console.log(post.content)
            })
        })
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                {!this.props.loaded
                    ? <h1>loading...</h1>
                    :
                    <div>
                        {this.props.posts.data.map(post => {
                            return(
                                <div>
                                    <h2>{post.title}</h2>
                                    <p>{post.content}</p>
                                </div>
                            )
                        })}
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const Home = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Main)
```

action:

```
export function fetchAllPosts(){
    return{
        type: 'FETCH_ALL_POSTS'
    }
}

export function receivedAllPosts(posts){
    return{
        type: 'RECEIVED_ALL_POSTS', 
        post_list: posts
    }
}

export function getAllPosts(){
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(fetchAllPosts())
        return fetch('/api/posts')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => {
                dispatch(receivedAllPosts(json.data))
            })
            .catch(error => {

            })
    }
}
```

reducer:

```
export function posts(state = {loaded: false}, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case 'FETCH_ALL_POSTS':
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                'loaded': false
            })
        case 'RECEIVED_ALL_POSTS':
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                'data': action.post_list, 
                'loaded': true
            })

        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

in the `console.log()` in the `componentDidMount()`, I do see the data got fetched, so it means it is in the state, but not applied into the `render()`,  i don't know why.

Comment: can you provide actioncreators and reducer.. and getAllPosts func ?. is that actual code?

Comment: @Utro just added the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of a simple reason: you should use `this.props.posts.loaded`, instead of `this.props.loaded`.

When you set your state to props:

```
function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
        posts: state.posts
    }
}
```

Here `state.posts` is actually the object from your reducer:

```
{
  'data': action.post_list, 
  'loaded': true
}
```

So similar to use access your posts list via `this.props.posts.data`, you should use `this.props.posts.loaded`. I believe you can debug through `debugger` or `console.log` easily.

A live code: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/agongdai/5851werm/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using multiple reducers with a root reducer, then you should also provide your reducer's name to the `mapStateToProps` function.

e.g:

rootreducer.js:

```
import posts from './posts';
const rootReducer = combineReducers({ posts });
```

component:

```
function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
        posts: state.posts.posts
    }
}
```